# PHP Session Difficulties

Tags: php, session, forms

I am trying to start a PHP session to store data from a form while a user logs on and then display it on a page after they have logged on. All attempts so far have failed and I don't see what I am doing wrong. So this is my procedure if you can tell me where I have gone wrong.

Step 1

First Page has a form on it that has received data from earlier. Some of this data needs to go into the session so at the very top of the page before anything else is.

```
<?php

session_start();

 $_SESSION['booking-form'] = array('GT_title' => $SEStitle, 'GT_actual_duration' => $SESactualduration, 'cal_startdate' => $SEScalstartdate, 'GT_picture' => $SESpicture, 'GT_total_duration' => $SEStotalduration, 'GT_total_dives' => $SEStotaldives, 'GT_total_price' => $SEStotalprice, 'GT_total_duration' => $SEStotalduration, 'GT_specifications' => $SESspecifications);
?>
```

Step 2

The user logs on

Step 3

Upon success the user is directed to another page which for now is called bookinginitial.php.

Step 4

The code on bookinginitial .php is as follows. I have set it up with 3 possibilities of how it could collect

```
    <?php

session_start();

 $_SESSION['booking-form'];
  echo $_POST['SEStitle'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php $_SESSION['booking-form'];

echo $_POST['SEStitle'];
?> 

<?php
        echo $_POST['SEStitle']; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now obviously that is not correct. Whether it is with the array of the session I don't know as I have just started with PHP and am doing my best.

Any help would be appreciated.

Marvellous,

Comment: try var_dump( $_SESSION ) and you will see the inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what troubles you, so I'll mention it on the suspicion that is what you meant with "I have set it up with 3 possibilities..".

This line by itself does nothing:

```
 $_SESSION['booking-form'];
```

And I assume you actually meant to wrap it as a conditional. The syntax for which would be:

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);   ########### for debugging purposes  ###########

if ($_SESSION['booking-form']) {

    echo $_POST['SEStitle'];

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>...
    <?php
}
elseif ($_SESSION['booking-form']) {
    ...
```

The second condition is possibly meant to check for something else. But I have no idea what your page actually does.

Comment: I'm not getting chaps, Ive tried everything said I am obviously missing something. Perhaps it would be best ive I explained what I am trying to do. 1) Client fills in form. 2)Form submits to interim page where they check what they have ordered. 3)client logs in meaning form data is lost. Use of the Session was to hold on to that form data and display it on another page (the success page) once they have logged in. The log in system works fine it is simply a matter of holding onto this date. I have never used a session before and cannot see how to do this from the documentation.

Comment: @RobinKnight: I think your usage of the $_SESSION array is actually fine. I was just concerned about the processing logic here. Try the `print_r()` tests like Byron said.

Comment: OK I put print_r() in on the receiver page. Nothing happens. Like I said I do not know where I am supposed to put it. Documentation says it all goes at the top of the page before <html>. I don't see how anything can be shown from up there but I have put it there and tried it in multiple other places as well. Nothing happens. This is because I don't know how to use it and the documentation is no help so I ask. PAGE 1 I want to hold on to an input value on that page called 'test'. On page 3 I want to show it. How do I do that. Then  I should understand. Thanks.

Comment: @RobinKnight: You should put `print_r($_SESSION);` in the line after `session_start();` so it can read and print its contents. See my edit. This works despite being situated before the `<html>` start tag, because browsers display it anyway even if it is mangled and invalid html.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to access the session array.

`echo $_SESSION['booking-form']['SEStitle'];`

The `$_POST` array is only set when you send fields from a form.

Comment: OK chaps but where does it go. I have put that in 2 places now on the temporary received and nothing happens.

Comment: Do a `print_r($_SESSION)` to see the content of the session. Looking at your array again, it should actually be `echo $_SESSION['booking-form']['GT_title'];`